# Magento 2 registration form validation not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, validation

I've copied across register.phtml across to my theme. I've changed nothing as of yet but now the JS validation doesn't work.

Is there something else I need to copy across?

**EDIT:**

[theme name]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Comment: Without copied its work for you have you checked first?

Comment: Yes if i delete it, it works fine with the fall back

Comment: Plz show your override template path

Comment: added to original

Comment: It's not working on the login/register page either after I just checked

Comment: Your file override is perfect.

Comment: Just try to run deploy command, remove var folder and clear your browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just run deploy command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder from root.

Clear your browser cache and try again.